# find: suppress "Directory not empty"

Tags: find

To delete all non-hidden files and directories last modified longer than 2 weeks ago, I'm using:

```
find ~ -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -name "[!.]*" -delete
```

This will sometimes print error messages "Directory not empty".

I would like to silence these errors (as I get notified about them when running as a cronjob) but I would still like `find` to delete directories when they are empty and older than 2 weeks.

Comment: Instead of -delete, you can use -exec with rm -rf

Comment: @RamanSailopal, that could recursively  delete directories that contain recently modified files!

Comment: Fair point. Always run the find without delete or exec first to ensure that the listing is as you expect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `find` supports the `-maxdepth` and `-delete` non-standard extensions, it likely also supports `-empty`, so you can do:

```
find ~ -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 ! -name '.*' \( ! -type d -o -empty \) -delete
```

(that is, only attempt to delete directories that are empty)

Note that `-delete` implies `-depth` (which you'd expect as you'd want to delete a file before the directory that contains it).

However, deleting a file from a directory updates the modification time of that directory. That  means that directories won't be deleted if they contained old files that have been successfully deleted even if they were old themselves initially.

Here, you may want to not delete any directory at all:

```
find ~ -mtime +14 ! -name '.*' ! -type d -delete
```

Or record the list of old directories before deleting any file, delete the non-directory files, and then delete the directories in the recorded list:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) &&
{
  rm -f -- "$tmp"
  find ~ -depth -mindepth 1 ! -name '.*' -mtime +14 -type d -print0 >&3
  find ~ -mtime +14 ! -name '.*' ! -type d -delete
  xargs -r0 rmdir <&4 2> /dev/null
} 3> "$tmp" 4< "$tmp"
```

Or using `moreutils` `sponge` (though that means storing the whole list of files in memory):

```
 find ~ -depth -mindepth 1 ! -name '.*' -mtime +14 -type d -print0 |
   sponge sh -c '
     find ~ -mtime +14 ! -name ".*" ! -type d -delete
     xargs -r0 rmdir'
```

Or `zsh`'s `=(...)` form of process substitution:

```
{
  find ~ -mtime +14 ! -name ".*" ! -type d -delete
  xargs -r0 rmdir
} < =(find ~ -depth -mindepth 1 ! -name '.*' -mtime +14 -type d -print0)
```

Or you could delete all empty directories regardless of whether they're old or not:

```
find ~ -mindepth 1 ! -name '.*' \( -mtime +14 ! -type d -o -type d -empty \) -delete
```

Comment: @NathanKulzer, the temp file needs to be opened twice, once for reading once for writing both don't share the same *open file description*. Otherwise, if using the same fd in read+write mode, after the writing, the cursor on that fd would be at the end of the file, and `xargs` would have nothing to read.